# CSRF Problem in Zend Framework 3 with Ajax Form

Tags: php, csrf, zend-framework3

I am having an intermittent problem with the CSRF element in a ZF3 ajax form. I am using the following to configure the element

```
$this->add([
     'type' => Element\Csrf::class,
     'name' => 'onlineGameCsrf',
     'options' => [
         'csrf_options' => [
             'timeout' => 600,
         ],
     ],
 ]);
```

and including in the form using

```
echo $this->formRow($form->get('onlineGameCsrf'));
```

Most of the time this works as it should but every so often, maybe one in ten times, it fails. The logs show the following error.

```
[notSame] => The form submitted did not originate from the expected site
```

I have tried a couple of 'fixes' that I have found on SO and elsewhere. The first was moving $form->prepare() to the view file and another was to increase the timeout in the configuration. Neither of these worked, though perhaps I wasn't increasing the timeout enough (I went to a max of 2000).

I am using the same CSRF element elsewhere in the site on non-ajax forms and it is working correctly with no issues.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you keep track of how long a period expired between loading the form and submitting the form? That specific error is given when the CSRF token generated for the form has expired.

Comment: I didn't rkeet. Do you think I should play with the timeout value more?

Comment: Well, no. It's a bit of a security thing. By default it's 600, because 10 minutes should be plenty to fill out a form. Else you can just submit twice (assuming you return the form data to the client if the form is invalid), the second time it then has a new csrf token.

Comment: I did a couple of tests with the form where I loaded it and left it sitting for about 10 mins and there were no errors so I think the session is ok. However, when you mentioned about submitting the form twice it got me thinking about the fact that I've just set up Google's recaptcha which is integrated into the form validation. I think that might be worth looking into in case it is somehow doing a double submission. Thanks rkeet.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'Timeout' and not 'Session' in my previous comment.

Comment: Aight, good luck ;-) And throwing an error at users who have left a form sitting there for too long might not be bad, depending on the situation ;-) E.g. not needed for a newsletter sign-up, but would be good to do for inputting corporate financial results, or something ;-)